# Local repainting in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint

How can I repaint local field on `JPanel`? I'm writing a snake game. When the snake moves to the next cell, we need to repaint only changed cell (not whole `JPanel`). Cell can throw `PropertyChangeEvent` object and then I can call repaint(x, y, h, w) method. Is this the right way?

Comment: what is your Cell? Is that a panel? ie. Is the whole grid one JPanel, or are all the individual cells lots of JPanels?

Comment: Cell - object in model with field Owner. When owner changes Cell throws PropertyChangeEvent object and then im calculate coordinates on my grid. In my JPanel im painting only rectangle grid (binding on Field obj(wrapper on two level array)).

Comment: i cant tell what you mean. You need to post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'll assume that you really do want to use a panel instead of a table, though I think you may want to look into the JTable component because that may be better suited to your application.

The answer to your question is that you shouldn't explicitly request a repaint for a cell. Instead each cell should be represented as an instance of a JComponent subclass that contains code like the following:

```
public class SnakeGameCell extends JComponent {

    private boolean snakePresent;

    public boolean isSnakePresent() {
        return snakePresent;
    }

    public void setSnakePresent(boolean present) {
        if (snakePresent != present) {
            snakePresent = present;
            repaint();
        }
    }

}
```

In other words, each component should be responsible for knowing when it should be repainted and for making that happen when appropriate. It's rare to find a situation where it's appropriate for repaint() to be invoked "externally". To put it another way, don't have the controller class responsible for initiating the repaint -- make the thing (component) that needs to be repainted decide for itself.